# Как задать время запуска нового процесса?

Tags: c#, .net

Доброго времени суток!
Одним глазом взирайте на этот скриншот для представления: [http://imgur.com/a/rk7kU](https://imgur.com/a/rk7kU)

Подскажите пожалуйста, я из диалогового окна я получаю данные: время запуска, время финиша процесса, приоритет и его имя из listbox или если пользователь сам захочет ввести название системного процесса - введет его в textbox что ниже.

Вернув DialogResult.OK по нажатию на кнопку OK я должен получить готовый процесс, который осталось запустить.

И первая проблема, с которой я столкнулся - это присвоение времени запуска новому процессу, у свойства нету сеттера, только ReadOnly(get).

Вопрос: как создать процесс с заданным временем запуска, финиша, приоритета и имени?

Comment: Запустите его сами в нужное время. _Ваш К. О._

Comment: Если ваша программа не планирует быть резидентным планировщиком, а должна только создавать задачи, то смотрите API родного планировщика Win.

Comment: Посоветуйте лучше классы)

Comment: https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/ посмотрите тут, исходники доступны, можно подсмотреть идею если не хочется тащить всю либу в проект

Answer (score 2):

Тащить какой-нибудь сторонний планировщик типа Кварца или пытаться взаимодействовать с виндовым планировщиком задач, на мой взгляд, несколько тяжеловато для такой "одноразовой" задачи. Я бы воспользовался обычной задержкой по таймеру:

```
public void ScheduleProcess(ProcessStartInfo processInfo, DateTime dueTime)
{
    if (dueTime < DateTime.Now)
    {
        // следующие сутки
        dueTime = time.AddDays(1);
    }

    var delay = dueTime - DateTime.Now;
    Task.Delay(delay).ContinueWith(_ => Process.Start(processStartInfo));
}
```